# How to make GMail spam folder always visible?

Tags: google, email, gmail

The spam folder in GMail is always hidden and it becomes more and more uncomfortable
How to configure GMail Spam folder to be always visible?

Comment: This belongs on webapps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To whitelist individual email addresses:

Settings -> Filters -> Create a new filter. 
Fill in the emailaddress in the "From" field, click Next, and select "Never send to spam". Instead of an entire emailaddress you could use a partial address too, like @yourcompany.com to whitelist all mail from that domain name.

You can also just pick a mail from the spam box and click the button "Not spam". If you do this a few times for the same sender their mail will start ending up in your inbox too.

To always show the spam box:

Settings -> Labels

In the first list (system labels) look up 'Spam' and click the 'show' link next to it. Here you can set show/hide settings for all your other labels as well.